# Elegant solution for UIActionSheet mess

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to find an elegant solution to UIActionSheet problem.

I use UIActionSheets like this:

```
UIActionSheet * myChoices = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
    initWithTitle:nil
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
    destructiveButtonTitle:@"erase"
    otherButtonTitles: @"aaa", @"bbb", @"ccc", @"ddd", nil];
```

the problem is that in order to discover the option selected by the user, I have to use this:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    switch ([actionSheet tag]) {
           case 0: ... 
           case 1: ... 
           case 2: ... 
           case 3: ... 

        }
}
```

this case based on index is terrible, because if I change the order of the aaa, bbb, ccc, etc., on the action sheet I have to change the case order. This index stuff is not good as a solid solution.

I have tried to imagine a way to do that and become index independent but did not come any satisfactory solution. Using buttonTitleAtIndex is not good enough too, because my apps are localized and I would have to test for n titles for every entry. Any suggestions?

Comment: JUST USE "TAG" ... it's that easy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I created a block-based version of `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet`, I personally never use the delegate-based Apple version again.
**You can download my [`OHActionSheet`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHActionSheet) and [`OHAlertView`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAlertView) classes in my GitHub repository**.

Because they are based on the *completionBlock* pattern, they are more readable (all the code is at the same place, no common delegate for multiple `UIActionSheets`, …), and more powerful (because blocks also capture their context as needed).

```
NSArray* otherButtons = @[ @"aaa", @"bbb", @"ccc", @"ddd" ];
[OHActionSheet showSheetInView:self.view
                         title:nil
             cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
        destructiveButtonTitle:@"erase"
             otherButtonTitles:otherButtons
        completion:^(OHActionSheet* sheet, NSInteger buttonIndex)
 {
   if (buttonIndex == sheet.cancelButtonIndex) {
     // cancel
   } else if (buttonIndex == sheet.destructiveButtonIndex) {
     // erase
   } else {
     NSUInteger idx = buttonIndex - sheet.firstOtherButtonIndex;
     // Some magic here: thanks to the blocks capturing capability,
     // the "otherButtons" array is accessible in the completion block!
     NSString* buttonName = otherButtons[idx];
     // Do whatever you want with idx and buttonName
   }
 }];
```

---

### Additional Note: how to `switch/case` on NSStrings

Note that in the otherButtons part of the `if/else` test in your completion handler, you can then either test for the `idx` using a `switch/case`, or use my **[`ObjcSwitch`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/ObjcSwitch) category**, that will allow you to write `switch/case`-like code but for `NSStrings`, so you can have a code like this in your `OHActionSheet`'s completion handler:

```
NSUInteger idx = buttonIndex - sheet.firstOtherButtonIndex;
NSString* buttonName = otherButtons[idx];
[buttonName switchCase:
   @"aaa", ^{ /* Some code here to execute for the "aaa" button */ },
   @"bbb", ^{ /* Some code here to execute for the "bbb" button */ },
   @"ccc", ^{ /* Some code here to execute for the "ccc" button */ },
   ..., nil
];
```

---

EDIT : Now that the latest LLVM compiler supports the new "Object Literals" syntax, you can do the same as `ObjcSwitch` using the compact syntax of an NSDictionary:

```
((dispatch_block_t)@{
   @"aaa": ^{ /* Some code here to execute for the "aaa" button */ },
   @"bbb": ^{ /* Some code here to execute for the "bbb" button */ },
   @"ccc": ^{ /* Some code here to execute for the "ccc" button */ },
}[buttonName] ?:^{
       /* Some code here to execute for defaults if no case found above */
})();
```

Comment: @AliSoftware Don't delete the repo this links to please. Leave the readme pointing to the two repos instead to maintain the URL.

Comment: @JamesBillingham Noted. But can I know why you want me to keep it instead of editing my answer to point to the two other repos and updated URL?

Comment: @AliSoftware Updating the post would be good too, but it's always good practice to maintain URLs rather than 404ing them.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to help (although not fully solve) this problem by using an array of values. It makes it so that you at least have a unified source of data. So by creating an array for your values in your viewDidLoad or whatever and when you create your action sheet you can change it to something like:

```
//where myValuesArray is an array of strings you declared in viewDidLoad
//myValuesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", @"ccc", @"ddd", nil];

UIActionSheet * myChoices = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
    initWithTitle:nil
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
    destructiveButtonTitle:@"erase"
    otherButtonTitles:nil];

for(NSString *title in myValuesArray)
{
    [myChoices addButtonWithTitle:@"LMNOP"];
}
```

Then in your clickedButtonAtIndex you are checking against the index of the exact same array with what I assume is your choices. With this you can also just update the array when you want to make changes. I hope this helps.

Comment: It has helped me be consistent. There may be a more pure solution but this is also quick and straight forward.

Comment: This is also what I usually do (see my answer) but using blocks-based action sheets is even much more powerful (no need to switch/case on the tag of the `UIActionSheet` if we use multiple `UIActionSheets` in the same ViewController, for example, and allows local variables capture too like in my example)

Comment: @rooster Be aware that your code have a problem, due to some trick/bug from Apple's own `UIActionSheet`: when your initial `otherButtonTitles` parameter is `nil`, no matter if you `addButtonWithTitle` afterwards, the `firstOtherButtonIndex` property of your sheet is never set and is still `-1` (except if they fixed this bug in latest versions of iOS, but wasn't the case back in 4.3). So you can't rely on it to compute the index to get the name of the button clicked from the `myValuesArray` array. _I encountered the same in my custom class, see the source code to understand how I fixed it._

Comment: Interesting. I've never used that property so I've yet to encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding a late answer for such an old question, but googling "UIActionSheet blocks" leads here so I thought I'd share with you this easy block implementation I wrote.

https://github.com/freak4pc/UIActionSheet-Blocks

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but with iOS 8, the new `UIAlertController` class, allows you to create `UIAlertAction`s using blocks:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Pancakes", message: "Do you like them with:", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maple Syrup", style: .Default, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
    println("Picked syrup")
}))

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Jam", style: .Default, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
    println("Jam? eh?")
}))

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I HATE PANCAKES", style: .Destructive, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
    println("You monster.")
}))
```